# ASP.Net Event Validation fails on Android phone browser

Tags: asp.net, android, eventvalidation

We're running a fairly large site, and a lot of our visitors have started using their Android based cellphones to visit the site. However when they try to login, we get an Event Validation error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.
>   Event validation is enabled using
>   
>   in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a
>   page. For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate
>   from the server control that
>   originally rendered them. If the data
>   is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this, without disabling Event validation entirely ?

It isn't every single time they visit, but it is often enough that it's a problem.

Also we never get these on PC-based browsers (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc.)

EDIT:

The page this happens on has no updatepanels, no custom __doPostback code, etc. It's pretty much vanilla with a simple LinkButton that causes the postback.

Also this error occurs on a bunch of other pages as well (Just found out about that now), so I doubt it's a lone design fault.

I think it's more likely it's an issue with the Android based browser and ASP.Net in general.

Comment: You need to provide more informations to give a solution on that - you can search to find where the error comming from, by starting disable the stateview in some controls on your page - for the start.

Comment: View this as an idea:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420635/datagrid-button-invalid-postback-or-callback/3421436#3421436

Comment: I updated the question with some info. However I cannot see how this could be viewstate related, as event validation just checks whether the input posted corresponds to a list of valid values ?

Comment: I also see this in our logs for ANY ASP.NET app that uses viewstate validation - on Android devices using the Apple Webkit (per the browser config string). Does the Android browser corrupt the viewstate possibly? I know that some older versions of Safari had a smaller max length for hidden fields and caused a similar issue. Perhaps the WebKit browser on teh Andriod has a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969548

the reason I think this is the case is that I can't duplicate this when I browse normally on my Android simulator, but I CAN if I click on a button before the page ifnishes loading.  Also, even the 3G networks are slow enough that this scenario is likely, as impatient users will click as soon as they see the option they want.